# Adding a jquery script to my html results in a blank page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a working html page, and what I want to do is use jquery to include a footer.  However, whenever I actually put any jquery in a  tag, it causes the page to go blank, and I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Here is an abbreviated version of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="index-page">
<head>
    <title>Data</title>
    <!-- TODO: SEO goes here-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Stuff goes here </h1>
    <h2> other stuff here </h2>
    <div id="footer"></div>

    <!-- ============== Scripts ============== -->
        <!-- extern libs -->
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- TODO: switch out with our cdn-->
            <script>
                        $('#footer').load('footer.html');
            </script>
        <!-- config/init -->
            <script src="scripts/init.js"></script>
            <!-- services -->
            <!-- modules -->
                <!-- These files bind DOM elements to the JS Application Logic -->
                <script src="scripts/modules/indirect.hover.module.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I take out the  tags that include code to load footer.html, everything loads fine.  But as soon as I include those tags, the page is blank, and I don't know why.

A minimised version of footer.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="images/fonts/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,300italic,400italic,600italic">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <footer>
     <h1>stuff here</h1>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you remove all your other script does it works? Can you post the minimal not working code on JSFiddle so we can try?

Comment: **How many tags** are you using to try to load an external footer? Can you provide the HTML contents of `footer.html`?

Comment: Here is the link (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp) which you maybe will interest in for HTML <Footer> tag.

Comment: I've added the code for footer.html.

Comment: Ludovic: Rremoving the other scripts doesn't help.

Comment: @Mary Can you reproduce the problem on JSFiddle? Please post your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ save it, and send the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use document ready.

Also...is footer.html actually a file available in the directory that is serving this current file??
Because if not...it could be a case of the script not finding the file.  Perhaps you need ('../footer.html') or something similar.  Check your directory structure

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#footer').load('footer.html');
        });
        </script>
```

Judging by your updated code showing footer.html

You should change your footer file to just be

```
 <footer>
   <h1>stuff here</h1>
  </footer>
```

Thats it..
You dont need to redeclare anything really. (scripts, css head, html etc)
Just have the content you want to load.

Get rid of doctype, css files and all other irrelevant code

Comment: footer.html is in the same folder as index.html, which is the page with the script, and I tried using document ready.  What seems to happen is that the page loads momentarily, and then it goes blank.